# Different language settings for website and API

Tags: django

I have an application with two languages, Farsi and English. This application provides a website which uses Django templates and a simple API with two endpoints using pure Django.

**Now I'm facing an issue I can't solve:** I want the website to load in Farsi by default and the API to load in English. I have set the `LANGUAGE_CODE` to `'en'` so everything loads in English by default. I'm not using session or cookies.

Is there anyway I can tell the website to change the language to Farsi while keeping the API in English? Will I have to use cookies for this (I can't go about implementing sessions)? If so will it also affect the API? 
I have read the Django docs multiple times and still can't figure out the right way to go about this. Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: The user can switch between languages on the website, I just want the default to be in Farsi. Thought I should add that.

Comment: have you localised you website for both the languages...

Comment: @abhikumar22 Currently I can switch between both languages from the website.

Comment: you can set default language for in your settings.py file

Comment: @abhikumar22 I have already done that as I have stated in my main question. My problem is that I need the API to use English by default and the website to use Farsi by default. Changing the default language settings affects both of them.

Comment: api's you mean rest api's ???

Comment: You want that your API remain in English but your website can be chose in both language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a *request* middleware to set the language to English for the API, assuming the API URLs being with `/api/`:

```
from django.utils import translation

class APILanguageMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response 

    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.path.startswith('/api/'):
            lang_code = 'en'
            translation.activate(lang_code)
            request.LANGUAGE_CODE = translation.get_language()

        return self.get_response(request)
```

Rather than hardcoding you can also take the value from `settings` e.g. you can set:

```
API_LANG_CODE = 'en'
```

and then you can do:

```
from django.utils import translation
from django.conf import settings

class APILanguageMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response 

    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.path.startswith('/api/'):
            lang_code = getattr(settings, 'API_LANG_CODE', 'en')
            translation.activate(lang_code)
            request.LANGUAGE_CODE = translation.get_language()

        return self.get_response(request)
```

You can also do the same for the starting URL path.

Note that, if you have the `LocaleMiddleware` in your `MIDDLEWARE` setting, you must put this one **after** `LocaleMiddleware`.

---

As an enhancement to the above, you can handle the **`Accept-Language`** header, so that when a client specifically passes the languages to pick from, you can select accordingly (based on support and priority) instead of hardcoding to English in that case.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default language by using the standard Django `LANGUAGE_CODE` setting:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = "es-es"
```

You can turn on per-request language requests by adding LocalMiddleware to your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    ...
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'
]
```

By default all available languages will be supported.If you only wish to support a subset of the available languages, use Django's standard LANGUAGES setting:

```
LANGUAGES = [
    ('de', _('Farsi')),
    ('en', _('English')),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can let that your language determined in url pattern. With this technique your api can be available in different language like this: `http://your_domain/en/your_api` or `http://your_domain/fa/your_api`. You can read more in [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#module-django.conf.urls.i18n) link. Also I suggest read [enter link description here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#module-django.conf.urls.i18n) link to find out how django determine your language code. In your scenario I suggest first set these code in your setting:

```
LANGUAGES = [
('fa', _('Farsi')),
('en', _('English')),
]

...

LANGUAGE_CODE = "fa"  # Django uses this language as the default translation
```

Then define your url file as follow:

```
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

urlpatterns = [
path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path(_('admin/'), admin.site.urls),
    path(_('your_app/'), include('your_app.urls')),
)
```